# DigitalOcean REST API Call From CMD Using cURL Returns Error

Tags: curl, cmd, command-prompt, digital-ocean

I'm not sure that this is the best place to ask this, but the DigitalOcean community has been less than helpful and I can't find any other sources to help with this issue. When I try to make a cURL request to shutdown a VPS, it returns the following error:

```
{"id":"bad_request","message":"Your request body was malformed."}
```

Despite the fact that I copied the cURL request verbatim from their API docs. When I run it in a Linux terminal, it works just fine, leading me to believe it's an issue with cURL specific to CMD.

This is the code, copied verbatim from their API docs:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer APITokenHere" -d '{"type":"shutdown"}' "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/VPS_IDHere/actions"`

Comment: Can you share the exact command (private information removed) you're using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure windows' cmd.exe treats quotes different than a linux shell, I don't really know how to fix it though.

Comment: Any idea where I can find out?

Comment: I would try with `-d "{'type':'shutdown'}"` or, if the API rejects the single quotes, the usual approach is `-d "{\"type\":\"shutdown\"}"` escaping argument inner double quotes

Comment: Yea, I figured it out. Escape is with \.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is JSON related.

First, make sure your JSON is valid with a tool like https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print.

Like mc-nd said, on Windows, the CMD prompt does something weird with quotes, so escaping them like so should fix the problem:
`-d "{\"type\":\"shutdown\"}"`

It might also be possible to run the command in PowerShell, where single quotes work generally the same way as in Unix shells.